# Calculate datetime from datatimeoffset

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datetimeoffset

I have a datetimeoffset value as 11/22/2016 05:20 AM with an offset of -06:00. I want to get the result as 11/21/2016 11:20 PM after reducing the offset from the time value. I tried

```
date.UtcDateTime
```

but it gives me the result as 11/22/206 11:20 PM . What is the way to get the preferred result from datetimeoffset value

Comment: Think that ```11/22/2016 05:20 AM``` is already reduced. To get UTC time you need add 6h to ```11/22/2016 05:20 AM -6:00```, and your will get ```11/22/206 11:20 PM```

Comment: Central time is 6 hours behind UTC, represented as -06:00 (as in UTC - 6 hours).  So you have to add 6 hours to get UTC time, not subtract.

Comment: But the answer I need is time value -offset value . It should be 11/21/2016 11:20 PM. 6 hours deducted by the given time

Comment: @udaya726 If you want to subtract 6 hours for whatever reason then just do `date.AddHours(-6)`.  But just so you know you're changing the time from the -06:00 timezone to the -12:00 time zone.

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows that when a DateTimeOffset is created, the year, month, day, hour, minute, etc. are interpreted as a local time in the time zone specified by the offset (in udaya726's case, -6 hours). The default output, "11/22/2016 05:20:00 -06:00", should be read as "November 22, 2016, 5:20 AM in the time zone 6 hours behind Greenwich."

```
using System;

public class StOv4
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Time in question: 11/22/2016 05:20 AM with an offset of -06:00
        TimeSpan questionOffset = new TimeSpan(-6, 0, 0);
        DateTimeOffset questionTime = new DateTimeOffset(2016, 11, 22, 5, 20, 0, 0,
            questionOffset);
        Console.WriteLine("Time with {0} offset: {1}", questionOffset, questionTime);
        // "u" format specifier indicates string is to represent UTC time.
        Console.WriteLine("UTC time: {0}", questionTime.ToString("u"));

    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Time with -06:00:00 offset: 11/22/2016 05:20:00 -06:00
UTC time: 2016-11-22 11:20:00Z
```